# Stuck with Facebook like box for months

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-likebox

Never had such problems with any of the software in my life.

I have a facebook page http://www.facebook.com/zelife.ru

and all the time I try to create a likebox code for inserting it on my web-site I see this:

"Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in."

As far as I understand, I need to get an ID, where should I get it?

Thanks in advance.

Art

Answer (score 3):

The facebook like-box is designed for facebook **pages** only! You are trying to use your profile, that's why you're getting an error.